# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function at HTMLDocument

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

After updating woocommerce, I'm Getting this console error:

> (index):600 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a
>   function
>       at HTMLDocument. ((index):600)
>       at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

and this is the script:

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#email-pdf-form").bootstrapValidator({
      message: "This value is not valid",
      feedbackIcons: {
        valid: "fa fa-check",
        invalid: "fa fa-times",
        validating: "fa fa-spin fa-spinner"
      },
      fields: {
        sender_email: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "Your email is required"
            }
          }
        },
        sender_name: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "Your name is required"
            }
          }
        },
        receiver_email: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "Recipient email is required"
            }
          }
        },
        receiver_name: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: "Recipient name is required"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This is a custom mage plugin that validates info here https://thesafaripartners.feedmybeta.com/tour/vfbc/

After I updated the woocommerce plugin it crashed my page. It was working fine before. I think it has to do something with Jquery but I can't figure it out.

Comment: sounds like you probably didn't include the bootstrapvalidator code in your page

Comment: Try to make jQuery the first import. This `<script>var jquery_placeholder_url = 'https://thesafaripartners.feedmybeta.com/wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms-placeholders/jquery.placeholder-1.0.1.js';</script><script type='text/javascript'>` must not be before the jquery declaration

Comment: ADyson I did call the code before: /**
     * Register form validation script
     * 
     * 
     * @return void
     */
 public function register_validation_script() {
  wp_register_script( 'bootstrapValidator', plugins_url( 'assets/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '0.5.0');
 }

Comment: Where is your validation script placed? I haven't find this.

Comment: This is the entire code where this is happening: [link](https://gist.github.com/viscosho/ea4fe351a55d2a6619786c62ca70e1e8)

Comment: and the file actually exists at that location? Check your browser's network tools when the page is loading to see whether the bootstrapValidator.min.js file gets loaded successfully or not (a 200 OK for that file would be a success, anything else is failure) and whether it's loaded _after_ the jQuery and bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the validator script is not included. You need to use wp_enqueue_script with action that include other scripts. Try this code:

```
function add_validation_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapValidator',
                      plugins_url( 'assets/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js',  dirname(__FILE__) ),
                      array( 'jquery' ),
                      '0.5.0' );
  }    

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_validation_script' );
```

Comment: I added the scrip, see the code please, not working https://gist.github.com/viscosho/ea4fe351a55d2a6619786c62ca70e1e8

Comment: Add this to functions.php

Comment: I did, added the function , see here: https://gist.github.com/viscosho/ab8d68eae011139797f185c751c99188

Comment: That is file of your plugin, use the functions.php of your theme

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the script but not really adding/enqueueing it.
So instead of `wp_register_script(...)` use `wp_enqueue_script(...)` function.

You would use the code that @alexander-z was kind to provide.
Or you could leave the register and then right after it (or any other place that runs after the register) add :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapValidator');
```

Also make sure the `wp_enqueue_script` of your script is called after the jQuery is registered or with `jquery` as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

After enqueue your script file using **'wp_enqueue_script'** hook try to Change the following code in your js file.

Change

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

hope this will work.